# Evaluate/Execute Golang code/expressions like js' eval()

Tags: go, eval

**Is there a eval() like method on golang?**

Evaluate/Execute JavaScript code/expressions:

```
var x = 10;
var y = 20;
var a = eval("x * y") + "<br>";
var b = eval("2 + 2") + "<br>";
var c = eval("x + 17") + "<br>";

var res = a + b + c;
```

The result of res will be:

```
200
4
27
```

Is this possible in golang? and why?

Comment: You can use [go-exprtk](https://github.com/Pramod-Devireddy/go-exprtk) package to evaluate any kind of mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is this possible in golang? and why?

No, because golang is not that kind of language. It is intended to be compiled, not interpreted, so that the runtime does not contain any “string to code” transformer, or indeed knows what a syntactically correct program looks like.

Note that in Go as in most other programming languages, you can write your own interpreter, that is, a function that takes a string and causes computations to be done accordingly. The choice of the Go designers is only not to force a feature of such dubious interest and security on everyone who did not need it.

Comment: It seems that it is possible to implement an `eval` function in Go using an embedded interpreter such as [Yaegi](https://github.com/traefik/yaegi).

Comment: Evidently it's not "of such dubious interest". And not every writer of code has outward facing security concerns.

Answer (score 21):

Its perfectly possible. At least for expressions, which seems to be what you want:

Have a look at:

- https://golang.org/src/go/types/eval.go
- https://golang.org/src/go/constant/value.go
- https://golang.org/pkg/go/types/#Scope

You'd need to create your own `Package` and `Scope` objects and `Insert` constants to the package's scope. Constants are created using `types.NewConst` by providing appropriate type information.

Comment: Is it concurent-safe?

Answer (score 4):

There is no built-in eval. But it is possible to implement evaluation which will follow most of GoLang spec: [eval (only expression, not a code) package on github](https://github.com/apaxa-go/eval) / [on godoc](https://godoc.org/github.com/apaxa-go/eval).

Example:

```
import "github.com/apaxa-go/eval" 
...
src:="int8(1*(1+2))"
expr,err:=eval.ParseString(src,"")
if err!=nil{
    return err
}
r,err:=expr.EvalToInterface(nil)
if err!=nil{
    return err
}
fmt.Printf("%v %T", r, r)   // "3 int8"
```

It is also possible to use variables in evaluated expression, but it requires pass them with theirs names to Eval method.

Comment: eval package linked here no longer maintained

Answer (score 1):

This [parsing](https://golang.org/pkg/go/parser/#example_ParseFile) example parses GO code at runtime:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "go/parser"
    "go/token"
)

func main() {
    fset := token.NewFileSet() // positions are relative to fset

    src := `package foo

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func bar() {
    fmt.Println(time.Now())
}`

    // Parse src but stop after processing the imports.
    f, err := parser.ParseFile(fset, "", src, parser.ImportsOnly)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    // Print the imports from the file's AST.
    for _, s := range f.Imports {
        fmt.Println(s.Path.Value)
    }

}
```

Comment: This is a simple AST operation, not runtime evaluating

Answer (score 1):

[go-exprtk](https://github.com/Pramod-Devireddy/go-exprtk) package will probably meet all kinds of your needs to evaluate any kind of mathematical expression dynamically.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/Pramod-Devireddy/go-exprtk"
)

func main() {
    exprtkObj := exprtk.NewExprtk()

    exprtkObj.SetExpression("x * y")

    exprtkObj.AddDoubleVariable("x")
    exprtkObj.AddDoubleVariable("y")

    exprtkObj.CompileExpression()

    exprtkObj.SetDoubleVariableValue("x", 10)
    exprtkObj.SetDoubleVariableValue("y", 20)

    a := exprtkObj.GetEvaluatedValue()
    
    exprtkObj.SetExpression("2 + 2")
    exprtkObj.CompileExpression()

    b := exprtkObj.GetEvaluatedValue()

    exprtkObj.SetExpression("x + 17")
    exprtkObj.CompileExpression()

    c := exprtkObj.GetEvaluatedValue()

    res := a + b + c

    fmt.Println(a, b, c, res)
}
```